# Node HTTP library ignoring timeout argument during TCP handshake?

Tags: node.js, http, timeout, nodes

I have following code. It sends simple GET request to the target server.

However when there's no webserver listening on given IP address, node keeps hanging for around 2 minute+ - totally disrespecting timeout value - which should be few seconds.

I've launched tcpdump and i noticed that node keeps sending SYN packets constantly to target server during these 2 minutes.

Why is this happening on http library? I tested alternative library (node-request) and timeout is working correctly there. However for some reasons, i can't use it and need to stick to lower level libs.

```
http = require('http');

const options = {
  hostname: '52.178.167.109',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'GET',
    timeout: 5000, //5s timeout
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  req.end();
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// Write data to request body
req.end();
```

```
root@abc:~# time node test.js
problem with request: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.178.167.109:80

real    **2m15.474s**  <-------
user    0m0.616s
sys     0m0.084s
```

Answer (score 0):

The timeout property is only applicable to socket inactivity. You want to use request.setTimeout to set a read timeout.  The github ticket https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12005 clarifies this.

Comment: Thanks. One of comments mentioned there, did the job.